# php foreach with multidimensional array do I need to use a key?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following multidimensional array called $responses and it looks like this when I do a print_r

[image: array]

My foreach loop looks like this but it's not working:

```
foreach ($responses as $response) { 
    $output[$response['poll_response_id']] = array(
        'response' => $response['response'],
        'response_vote_count' => 0,
        'voters' => ''
    );
}
```

I would like to get an output like this when I do a print_r($output)

[image: output array]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$output = array(); 
foreach ($responses as $key => $response) { 
     $output[$key] = array(
        'response' => $response[$key],
        'response_vote_count' => 0,
        'voters' => ''
     ); 
}
```

If it doesn't work, please do a "var_dump" on "$responses" instead of "print_r" because we didn't view how this variable is exactly defined.

Comment: Hi antoox, your code works perfectly. Thank you so much for taking your time to help me with this. I spent many hours trying to solve this on my own and learned a lot in the process.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a simple transformation to me:

```
$out = array_map(function($response) {
  return array(
    'response' => current($response),
    'response_vote_count' => 0,
    'voters' => '',
  );
}, $responses);
```